# Where are the preferences of an app on Android?

Tags: android, navigation, settings, preferences

On iOS I go to Settings > SomeApp and get its preferences (if it has some).

Where do I find this on Android? I've tried "Settings" > "Application Manager" to find out I can only clear the apps cache, delete it etc.

Thanks

Comment: `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml` ?

Comment: Sorry, not in a technical way. Through the GUI. Android >= 4.x

Comment: This is up to you. **If** an app has a Preference Screen, normally, it's  opened through a Button, a Menu or an ActionBar item click. You're left completely free. Even not to put any Settings in your app.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. End-user questions, like this one, belong elsewhere, such as https://android.stackexchange.com. That being said, each app is responsible for collecting its own app-specific settings, in its own app-specific UI, if and how the developer chooses.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. Thats what I needed to know. See my comment in the next answer.

Comment: There is a canned UI that you are welcome to use (`PreferenceFragment`, et. al.) for collecting bulk settings from the user, with a UI reminiscent of the Settings app. If you wish to use it, though, you are responsible for implementing that, linking to it from your app (e.g., action bar item), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, app settings are usually implemented in the app themselves not in the Settings app, like iOS. This changed a bit in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), because now you can adjust permissions settings in the Android Settings app, but all other settings should still actually be implemented in a settings page within the apps themselves. You usually get to it by clicking an item on the ActionBar at the top right of the screen within the app, or in a pull-out navigation drawer.

Luckily, Google provides a template for creating a settings activity, so it's pretty easy to implement one. You can select it from the new activity dialog, shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question which was obviously put a bit too end-user-like.

Comment: Great, glad to help. Luckily, Google provides a settings activity template to make it super easy to implement settings. See my edit above, and please accept my answer if you feel it solves your issue!